# Scrollview with multiple images and zoom

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, zooming, pinchzoom

I have a problem zooming images in my scrollview.
When there is only one image then it is working fine but when there are more images then the following images are on top of the first.
They keep there position but first is larger.

Do I have to update the offset of the following images or is there another approach?
When I zoom an

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.mainScrollView.delegate = self
    self.mainScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.mainScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0
    self.mainScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    self.mainScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.loadImages() 
    ...
}

@objc fund loadData() {
    ...
  scrollViewWidth = self.mainScrollView.frame.width
  scrollViewHeight = self.mainScrollView.frame.height
    for dImage in self.imgData! {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:offset, y:0,width:self.scrollViewWidth, height:self.scrollViewHeight))
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: dImage)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.imgViewArray.append(imageView)
        self.mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        offset += self.scrollViewWidth
        self.mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: offset, height: self.scrollViewHeight)
        }
    }
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {  
    let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / 
    scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.imageView = imgViewArray[Int(page)]
    return self.imageView
}
```

[image]

[image]

Here I zoomed the another image. Also wrong position.

[image]

Would be nice if someone can point me into the right direction.
Thank You!

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Is one Scrollview with images inside enough? Or do I need another Scrollview? One Scrollview to swipe through the images and for each image a Scrollview for panning and zooming?

Answer (score -1):

Add auto layout constraints to position the image views (spacing one below the other) within your scroll view's content view.

[UIScrollView tutorial to scroll and zoom content](https://www.raywenderlich.com/159481/uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started)